# Mariadb mysql_upgrade failed

Tags: mariadb

a have upgraded my DB server from 10.1.36 to 10.2.30 and after running command `mysql_upgrade` it fail at step 4. Please take a look on screenshot. Does anybody have idea what is wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you please look into your my.cnf and post the line beginning with `log_slow_queries = `

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to give mysql users read and execute permissions to /var/log/ and /var/log/mysql/ directory, before it can access /var/log/mysql/slow_log.CSV file.